# Why does using the “n--” operator in this code throw an error?

Tags: javascript, recursion, operators, decrement

This code works:

```js
function factorial(n){
  if(n==0){
   return 1;
  }else{
   return n* factorial(n-1);
  }
};

console.log(factorial(5));
```

This doesn't:

```js
function factorial(n){
  if(n==0){
   return 1;
  }else{
   return n* factorial(n--);
  }
};

console.log(factorial(5));
```

I was working on a simple challenge 'factorial' using recursion. can someone explain to me why I have to use 'n-1' and when I use 'n--' it gives me 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.'?

Comment: `n--` or `--n` - there's a difference - one works, the other doesn't (for obvious reasons)

Comment: Time to read up on post-increment and post-decrement operators.

Answer (score 2):

If you used

```
return n* factorial(n--);
```

what that does is it decrements `n`, and the `n--` expression evaluates to the value of `n` *before* the decrement. This is called post-decrement.

```js
let n = 3;
console.log(n--);
```

While you can use

```
return n* factorial(--n);
```

called pre-decrement, which will decrement `n` and have the expression evaluate to the value of `n` *after* the decrement, there's no sense in reassigning `n` at all here - you don't access it after the recursive call, after all. (the `n*` that comes before the recursive call has already been evaluated, but changing `n` *while* calling the recursive function looks like an easy source of confusion.) Calling `factorial` with `n - 1` makes the code's intent more clear, and so should be preferred:

```
return n* factorial(n - 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need the '--' in front of the variable or the code executes it after the variable is passed

```js
function factorial(n){
  if(n==0){
   return 1;
  }else{
   return n* factorial(--n);
  }
};

console.log(factorial(5));
```